# Unable to access Qt 6.2.4 archive

Tags: qt, qt-installer

Unable to access an older version of qt software from qt windows installer in the custom installation process.

I am trying to install Qt (6.2.4) from the qt windows installer to build Wireshark, but I am facing the issue of not being able to access the older version of qt (6.2.4) this issue [error screenshot] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDngu.png) Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The newer version of Qt Setup should allow this with a Qt account.
Which can be found here: https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer

To uninstall past versions of Qt use Qt Maintenance Tool.

#### In the Qt Setup installer

Pick the Custom Installer option when prompted. Then in Select Components select the Archive check box. *Press Filter to allow it to refresh*.

Click on the Qt drop down arrow in the center window and scroll down to Qt 6.2.4. Check the box and hit next and Qt will install your desired version.